# How to change a package import based on enviroment in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I have a project that is being run in a linux NodeJS server that is using Puppeteer.

It is something like this:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

export const handler = async (event: any) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: chromium.args,
        defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
        executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
        headless: chromium.headless,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });

    const { body } = event;

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
    const pageTitle = await page.title();
    await browser.close();
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'works!', pageTitle, body }, null, 2),
    };
};
```

I plan to use AWS Lambdas for specific files but the problem is that I can't use the `puppeteer` package in aws because it is too big(250mb+).

I have found a lightweight `puppeteer` package that works in AWS Lambdas and the only thing that changes in the code is the import, like this:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core';
```

Before, it was only `puppeteer` and for AWS, it is `puppeteer-core`. The problem is: I have way too many files importing the default `puppeteer` and I wouldn't like to change every file. Is there any way to change the import package/files based on the enviroment I'm running?

Like, if it is aws, use `puppeteer-core`, if it isnt, use `puppeteer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if you're running on lambda with [an env var](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html). From there it would probably make the most sense to make a wrapper, since adding the check in all files importing Puppeteer would lead to a lot of duplication. The only tricky part is that you're using ESM, so you could write something using dynamic imports, but it might be easier to use `createRequire`. Example (I did not test this so I'm not 100% sure if Puppeteer supplies an commonjs module, or if you'd need to `require(...).default`:

```js
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)
const inLambda = !!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT
const whichPackage = inLamda ? 'puppeteer-core' : 'puppeteer'
const getCorrectPackage = () => require(whichPackage)
export default getCorrectPackage()
```

Then this could be imported from `import puppeteer from './pup-wrapper.js'`